# What type of flags should I use?

Tags: discussion, flags

There are three very identical flags:

1. Needs details or clarity.

> This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

2. Needs more focus.

> This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

3. Needs debugging details.

> The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

And then there's these two also identical ones:

1. Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more.

> This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

2. Opinion-based.

> This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

When should I use which flag? As sometimes I flagged `Needs details and clarity` and it got closed as `Needs more focus` or `Needs debugging details` and vice versa. Does it make a difference how long it takes to be handled? Or should I just decide on a daily basis which one to use for that day?

Comment: Examples for first three: 1. "I want to an array". 2. "How do I sort an array; split a string; create a linked list; recursively calculate gravity; make pancakes; as well as compare numbers?" 3. "I am trying to sort an array but I get an error <no details on how it's being sorted and/or the error>" / Examples for second two: 1. "I need a book on arrays" 2. "Should I make my code yellow?"

Comment: The important thing to note about the different reasons is the _guidance_ they provide to both the question asker and other users. There is different information depending on the final close reason. In general you should favour the most specific applicable choice even if needs debugging details is just a special case of needs details or clarity.